# Installing CakePHP on Windows with Apache

Tags: apache, cakephp

I'm trying to install CakePHP on my Windows XP machine running Apache 2.2. I have installed the Cake folder in my doc root.

I've read the installation instructions that say to include this line in the httpd.conf file;

`<Directory /path/to/cake>`

Does anyone know how to translate that into Windows? I currently have the following in my conf file:

```
<Directory "C:/Apache/Apache2.2/htdocs/cakeapp/">
```

Whenever I uncomment this line it crashes Apache. I've tried switching the slashes to "\" and I tried taking the slash off the end.

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

May be useful for you to develop CakePHP under Windows, you can also use IIS7 with URL ReWrite Module. Download via Windows Web Platform Installer and read this [Installing CakePHP on IIS7](http://tobint.com/blog/installing-cakephp-on-iis-7/).

Or install [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/download.php)/XAMPP. They sets up all configuration stuff and you good to go after set up CakePHP a little. I mean database connection etc...

After all put your CakePHP project to "`.\your\apache\web\root`" related to your installation directory (mine is "`C:\wamp\www`", and my wamp is under "`C:\wamp`"). Let's say your project name "`asd123`", then you should simply put asd123 directory to "`.\your\apache\web\root\asd123`" (on my computer it should be "`C:\wamp\www\asd123`").

In `httpd.conf` write that line:

```
<Directory "./your/apache/web/root/asd123/">
```

(mine is `<Directory "c:/wamp/www/asd123/>`)

Comment: Please, do not use all this crapy html tag inside your answer, markdown is SO simple, do not use html..

Answer (score 1):

it's really simple and dont need to follow their instructions.

1. extract cakephp to something like c:/htdocs/web/mysite
   so it looks like

   mysite/app

   mysite/cake
2. done. 
   provided you set apache document root to c:/htdocs/web/
   you can visit your site at http://localhost/mysite

to be fancier:

3. in httpd-vhosts.conf, add

   < VirtualHost *:80>

   ServerName mysite.local

   DocumentRoot C:/htdocs/web/mysite

   < /VirtualHost>
4. in c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts, add

   127.0.0.1  mysite.local
5. restart apache
6. done. visit site at http://mysite.local

this is all based on the assumption that your apache/php/mysql is configged correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i had both

```
<Directory "C:/Apache/Apache2.2/htdocs">
```

and

```
<Directory "C:/Apache/Apache2.2/htdocs/cakeapp/">
```

in my conf file and it was causing the error. I commented out the first one, moved a css file and I was in business.